# Program's executable file to image in Java

Tags: java, windows, swing

I know this might seem a bit odd, but i have this requirement and I want to know if this is possible.

I have a java swing application that I select a file (program) and this program is added to a list. When the list is completed, i execute the list of programs (this is like a start-up manager).

What I want to do is somehow, grab the file that I select and display it as image to my UI. For common files like pdf, doc, txt this is easy, I just have a generic image for each type. But lets say I want to execute regedit.exe or msconfig.exe, I want to be able to grab its icon (picture below) .

[image]

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [FileSystemView.getSystemIcon(File)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileSystemView.html#getSystemIcon%28java.io.File%29).

It's a little limited (in that you will only get one size), but it's build in and doesn't require any additional libraries or JNA or JNI even...

```
File f = new File(...);
Icon icon = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemIcon(f);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the native icons you need JNI. Java has no default API for fetching the native icons in different sizes. Here are some startingpoints for windows & linux:

- [File icon overlay in java for windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9842530/file-icon-overlay-in-java-for-windows)
- [How do you get the icon, MIME type, and application associated with a file in the Linux Desktop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629172/how-do-you-get-the-icon-mime-type-and-application-associated-with-a-file-in-th)

If you do not need the exact native icons you can get the mimetype of the file and set a icon on your own:

- [Getting A File's Mime Type In Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51438/getting-a-files-mime-type-in-java)