# Method to implement Windows Explorer icon overlays with Java

Tags: java, java-native-interface, icons, overlay, explorer

I am writing a cloud-sync application in Java with .jni integration to virtualize a cloud file-system in windows explorer.

Now i want to implement icon overlays like owncloud to see the state of a node like this:

[image]

I found some solutions for C#. Is this also possible with Java if using a jni interface to get access to the Icon Handlers.

Anyone knows a existing solution?

P.S. Tha last question for this is 4 years old so there is eventually a new solution for modern systems with java8 in combination with a native .dll available.

Thank you for any hint.

Answer (score 2):

I just found a solution for Java 1.7+ in combination with native and jni dlls. Works with Windows Vista+, Mac and Linux.

"Liferay Nativity is a cross-platform library for adding icon overlays and context menus to file browsers."

You can find the GIT project here:

https://github.com/liferay/liferay-nativity

Anyone sucessfully integrated this? Trying to do a test implementation now.